# TypeError: getElementById is null using JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to check that user eneters valid name in english using latin alphabet and valid name in russian using cyrillic alphabet.

I'm having following `edit.jsp` form:

```
<body>
    <h1>${faculty.name}</h1>

    <div class="form">
        <form id="edit_faculty" action="controller" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="editFaculty" /> 
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name_ru"> Name (ru)</label> <input type="text"
                    name="name_ru" value="${requestScope.name_ru}" required />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name_eng"> Name (eng)</label> <input type="text"
                    name="name_eng" value="${requestScope.name_eng}" required />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="/Project/script/faculty-validation.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the `faculty-validation.js`:

```
    document.getElementById('name_ru').onkeypress = function(e) {
        return (/[А-Яа-я]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)));
    }

    document.getElementById('name_eng').onkeypress = function(e) {
        return (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)));
    }
```

I follow this links, but main answer's were to check the place in the page where programer put `script src tag`.

1. [Error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null when add text innerHTML using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038952/error-typeerror-document-getelementbyid-is-null-when-add-text-innerhtml-us)
2. [TypeError: document.getElementById() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654487/typeerror-document-getelementbyid-is-null)

I'm debugging this in Mozilla and getting TypeError. I also tried to modify js code with no success to:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('name_ru').onkeypress = function(e) {
        return (/[А-Яа-я]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` works with the `id` attribute, not `name`. I don't see `id` attributes for your input tags.

Replace:

```
<input type="text" name="name_ru" value="${requestScope.name_ru}" required />
```

with:

```
<input type="text" name="name_ru" id="name_ru" value="${requestScope.name_ru}" required />
```

and:

```
<input type="text" name="name_eng" value="${requestScope.name_eng}" required />
```

with:

```
<input type="text" name="name_eng" id="name_eng" value="${requestScope.name_eng}" required />
```

Comment: how to allow also backspace and whitspace for user ?

Comment: @Mark: for backspace you can add `if (e.keyCode === 8) { return true; }` to the first line of your functions. For whitespace it depends on what you want to achieve, so for example you could have something like `/[a-zA-Z ]/` for your regexp (there is a space after `Z`).

Comment: thank you for your explanation. also would you explain if it's a good idea to use key press events ? maybe is it better to check input on submit ?

Comment: @Mark: do whatever users find less confusing.